# How do I log out any user when using the cache session backend?

Tags: django, session, django-admin, logout, django-sessions

I am building a form into django admin where I can submit a user id and the system is expected to log the user out.

I cannot do `django.contrib.auth.logout()` because it does not take a user id as a parameter.

I also cannot query against `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session` because I am using the `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache` session engine.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could find to accomplish this is by doing something like

```
from django.conf import settings
SessionStore = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
SessionStore(session_id).delete()
```

You may notice that I don't have the code that connects a user id to a session id. This is because as far as I can tell, with the cache session engine by default there is no way to do that linking because the session key is only stored on the browser. The [key is a secure random string](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f9e9526800c921ae393ff58826daed51587b1727/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L146) and it [gets looked up](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L20) by the backend.

Therefore you will need to store the session id somewhere in your database and associate that key with your user.

In my case, I issue a set of tokens to the user at login time, so I was able to attach the session id to the token. Then when I initiate an admin action to forcibly logout a user, I can do

```
for token in Token.objects.filter(user=request.user):
    SessionStore(token.session_id).delete()
    token.delete()
```

Comment: Nice, the other solution is to add a boolean flag on the user model (force_logout) and have a middleware checking if the user is authenticated and force them to re-login and reset the flag back. I'm not sure which one is best